# Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Beta slow install

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Started the SP1 beta install at 8 am today and at 11 am decided that the progress bar looked decidedly hung at about 5%. I pushed cancel which gives a message saying its rolling back but leaves the progress bar hung at the same location for the last hour.

Is the SP1 beta installer just really slow or is there something wrong with my specific setup?

The PC itself is half decent (win7, x64, dual core, 4gb ram, etc...). Did your install go quicker?

Comment: Not a real answer, but i remember VS installs being notoriously slow depending what is installed. C++ was the main cuplit due to a signficiant amount of source file updates, iirc - at least in the 2008 times.

Comment: I never not had a problem with a beta installer.  Well, the uninstaller.  Tried it twice (VS2005, .NET 4.0) and it both cases my machine got fecked-up badly.  It is the last thing they work on.  Don't do this on a production machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there's something going awry with the downloader built into the web installer. I gave up on my second install attempt after another 5 hour session. My workaround was to use the SP1 iso file from MSDN (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=207267 - *Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Beta (x86 and x64) - **DVD***) as this ensures that all the files required by the SP are present before the installation begins. I dunno what options are available for people without an MSDN subscription though.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. ["VS 2010 Slowlly installation, win 7 x64"](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/c72a9fee-07a3-4843-8da0-c7fe0c278999)(sic) solved it for me.